CORS Error when importing third party javascript libraries in LWC
I'm encountering an issue while attempting to integrate a third-party library into my Lightning Web Component (LWC). Despite configuring CORS settings and remote site settings, I am unable to make the library work properly in the LWC. The LWC is embedded in Experience Cloud. The third-party library I am trying to integrate is a chatbot. I have added the URL to the CORS configuration and remote site settings.
Script that I am trying to import in LWC:
<script
   src="https://static.soulmachines.com/widget-snippet-1.12.0.min.js"
   data-sm-api-key="YOUR_API_KEY"
></script>

Here's my LWC code:
HTML:
<template>
    <div class="container"></div>
</template>

JavaScript:
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import WIDGET_SNIPPET from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/WidgetSnippet';

export default class YourComponent extends LightningElement {
    loaded = false;
    apiKey = '123';

    renderedCallback() {
        if (this.loaded) {
            return;
        }
        this.loaded = true;
    
        const scriptUrl = WIDGET_SNIPPET + (WIDGET_SNIPPET.includes('?') ? '&' : '?') + 'api_key=' + this.apiKey;
        console.log(scriptUrl);
    
        loadScript(this, scriptUrl)
            .then(() => {
                console.log('Widget Snippet loaded successfully');
                // If the script needs to perform initialization that LWC can handle
                this.initializeComponent();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Failed to load Widget Snippet', error);
            });
    }

    initializeComponent() {
        // Custom initialization logic here
        console.log('Component initialized');
    }

}

In the console, the script loads fine, but the bot is not showing up. I would really appreciate if you could provide help.
